# Can I use a water-based ultrasound-cleaner with oil?

Tags: ultrasound

I'd like to clean my bicycle chain with as little effort as possible, so I thought an ultra-sound cleaner would be best. Professional oil-based ultrasound cleaners are way too expensive for a hobbyist, but water-based ultrasound cleaners are pretty cheap. So I could just run it with oil.

Could this work or is it doomed to fail because you need different kinds of transducers (or something like that)?

I understand that the risk is all mine, so I won't sue any of you for damages. I'd just like a more qualified opinion than my own. I'm assuming here that the worst that could happen is that it doesn't work and I end up with an oil-smeared device that I need to properly dispose of. Oil is less conductive than water, so I see no risk of shorting the device.

Comment: If you are unable to determine the viability of your objective, consider that you can certainly clean a bicycle chain in a water based solvent, as long as it's not a motorcycle chain with internal O-rings. Chains get rained on and lubricants will displace the last rinse water.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Rain won't displace the lubricant inside the chain links like water-based ultrasound cleaning probably would. Chain lube is relatively viscous, it supposedly wouldn't replace the water inside. Hence my approach to ultrasound it in low-viscous oil, wipe it off and then lube it with normal chain lube.

Comment: water and detergent?

Comment: Detergent is a given when cleaning with water, otherwise you achieve hardly anything. That changes nothing wrt the lube inside the chain links.

Comment: In laboratory use, ultrasonic cleaners are often used in the "double bath" configuration - so you have a bottle or beaker in the outer bath (cheap water), and extra clean fluid in the inner bottle or beaker. I don't see any reason that fluid shouldn't be an oil or organic solvent. The cleaners I've seen have a stainless steel bath with a lid and nothing at all going through the walls.

Comment: Spot on @PeteW.  The one I use here wouldn't hold a container big enough for a bike chain, but I've cleaned up a freehub in a beaker of solvent, followed by water+detergent.  The bath itself is filled with plain water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I actually went ahead and bought a simple large (for an end-user device) ultra-sound cleaner and filled it with low-viscous oil. I operated it twice in the space of a few weeks. It still works and it does clean. The main challenge is to get the dirt out of the oil in the device's basin.

Comment: If you use water in lieu of oil, I think you are risking damaging the protective layer of the metal over a tight space, which may create more headaches down the road.

Comment: I know, that's what motivated this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In my lab we use ultrasound cleaners a lot, albeit to clean glassware but from all sorts of stains and dirt.

What I would suggest at first is that you try water + dishwashing liquid. Dishwashing liquid is formulated to bind partially to grease (surfactant effect).

Do let us know how it goes.

Comment: On bicycle chains, the will degrease the innards of the chain links which are then hard to "re-grease".

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to remove the grease from everywhere in the chain except the internal portions of the chain links?

Comment: The grease and the dirt, yes.

Comment: Then to me it sounds like you need to hand scrub. UT baths are DESIGNED to get gunk out of nooks and crannys that you otherwise couldn't access.

Comment: @AustinPrater The gunk is only on the outside of the chain. The inside contains clean low-viscous lube. If I clean it in an oil-based ultrasound cleaner, the inside lube should be replaced by oil from the bath if at all while the dirt on the outside will be removed.

Comment: Would it be OK if the oil in the inaccessible parts of the bicycle chain were replaced with say engine lubricating oil?

Comment: @JannPoppinga if you think the gunk is only on the outside, next time you change a chain that looks clean, drive the pins out and have a look inside the rollers.